# How to calculate absorbed heat by different painted colours on a steel container?

Tags: thermodynamics, absorption

I'm looking to understand how I can calculate the heat impact in a galvanized steel box with a cooling capacity of $0.25\;\mathrm{kW}$.

For example, what is the heating absorption of a box painted black and one painted white, and what's the impact on the box's heating capacity?

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you looking for measured data, a theoretical model, or something in between?

Comment: I have a calculator that compiles the heat generated by electronic equipment inside galvanized steel cabinets sitting outdoors. The heat is calculated in kW at the moment which is the unit of measure each of those pieces of kit come with in catalog. The steel box has a cooling capacity and the calculator measures how many pieces of kit we can put into the box before it surpasses the cooling capacity. This cooling capacity doesn't take into consideration the color of the box and we have boxes different coats of paint which impact the heat differently. How can I add this into the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know some things more, like the emissivity, and the input power, the surface the input power is applied to and the overall surface.

Simply calculate the absorbed power and the re-radiated (emitted) power:

$$ P = A_{abs}\cdot \epsilon \sigma T_{in}^4$$ (assuming an input source of temperature $T_{in}$).

And do the same for the re-radiated power, but assume the overall surface of the container to re-emit:
$$ P = A_{emit}\cdot\epsilon\sigma T_{container}^4$$

In equilibrium, both input and re-radiation power are equal. As is the emissivity as it's the same material. If you have additional heat sinks like a galvanized steel box... add that to the side of the re-emitted power as an additional term. Either case you can solve the resulting equation for the temperature of the container $T_{container}$ and compare results for different emissivities $\epsilon$ which represent the effect of black or white paint.

Comment: The input power is sunlight so it's not a fixed value that I can add in, but lets say the following, I know the emissivity for the galvanized steel box, and I know the expected total heat of a standard white galvanized steel box. If I put it in different terms and say, IF the galvanized steel box on a standard day with standard sunlight and with the standard color has an expected Heat Load of 0.36 kW, what Heat Load should I expect had that same box been painted black? is there an "absorption index" by color?the same way there's refraction a index if there is, that would suffice for me I think

Comment: You can calculate the sunlight's power easily. Take the solar constant and reduce it a bit due to whatever atmospheric conditions you want to allow. Typically 1000W/m² is a good guestimate for direct sunlight. The emissivity and absorption are the same thing: a grey radiator with $\epsilon = 0.1$ also only absorpts 10% of the incoming radiation (ignoring wavelength dependence either way). The actual value depends on the paint. Just make a guestimate... like 10% and 90% for white and black (or whatever suits you... it's only ballpark figures anyway)